# VPN to Windows Server 2012 on ec2 not routing

Tags: amazon-ec2, vpn, routing, windows-server-2012

I have a Windows Server 2012 instance on EC2 so I can VPN into the private network to access machines not exposed via a public IP.

I can connect to the Windows Server VPN by its public IP and authenticate correctly. I get an ip address on the private network.

The server is not routing packets from the VPN client to other machines in the private network on EC2.

What am I doing wrong?

> route print

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
  3...00 1c 42 72 46 c6 ......Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Network Connection
 27...........................fhx
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
  4...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
  5...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
  6...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      10.211.55.1      10.211.55.3   4235
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         On-link     173.31.21.112     11
      10.211.55.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       10.211.55.3   4491
      10.211.55.3  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.211.55.3   4491
    10.211.55.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.211.55.3   4491
    [PUBLIC IP OF SERVER]  255.255.255.255      10.211.55.1      10.211.55.3   4236
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1   4531
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1   4531
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1   4531
    173.31.21.112  255.255.255.255         On-link     173.31.21.112    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1   4531
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       10.211.55.3   4491
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     173.31.21.112     11
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1   4531
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.211.55.3   4491
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     173.31.21.112    266
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

ipconfig

```
Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : localdomain
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : fdb2:2c26:f4e4:0:693c:db02:9965:9279
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::693c:db02:9965:9279%3
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.211.55.3
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.211.55.1

PPP adapter fhx:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 173.31.21.112
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0

Tunnel adapter isatap.localdomain:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : localdomain

Tunnel adapter isatap.{0ED5745E-7C2A-4543-A6E5-C426914B2CD4}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

Comment: Do you have source/destination checking disabled for this instance?

Comment: I hadn't but even when disabling it I get the same result